# Finding number of new users

Tags: r

I'm using R, and have a data table of people playing a certain online game.

```
userId,  login,      country
132,     2017-01-01, A
133,     2017-01-01, B
133,     2018-01-01, B
432,     2018-01-01, A
```

I want to find the number of new users in each country in 2018, defined as the number of users that logged in in 2018 but not in 2017. For example, if the above data table were the entire data table, then country A would have 1 new user in 2018 (user 432), while country B would have 0 new users (as user 133 logged in in 2017).

What is the fastest way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table` is probably the fastest if you have a big dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, login := as.Date(login)]
data[, .(year = min(year(login)), country), by = userId
     ][, sum(year == 2018), by = country]
   country V1
1:       A  1
2:       B  0
```

Where data:

```
data <- fread("userId,  login,      country
132,     2017-01-01, A
133,     2017-01-01, B
133,     2018-01-01, B
432,     2018-01-01, A")
```

EDIT: Using similar logic in dplyr (which turns out much more verbose):

```
data %>% 
  mutate(year = year(as.Date(login))) %>%
  group_by(userId) %>%
  summarise(myear = min(year), country = unique(country)) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(n_new_users = sum(myear == 2018))

  country n_new_users
  <chr>         <int>
1 A                 1
2 B                 0
```

Edit2: Using similar logic (maybe not the best) in base R (with some pipes to keep track easier):

```
data$year <- as.integer(substr(data$login, 1, 4))
data %>% 
  aggregate(year ~ userId + country, ., min) %>%
  aggregate(year ~ country, ., function(x) sum(x == 2018))
  country year
1       A    1
2       B    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my alternative:

```
require(dplyr)
require(lubridate)
data %>%
  mutate(years = year(as.Date(login))) %>%
  group_by(userId) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>% # n will be >1 if a user is not new 
  filter(n == 1, years == "2018") %>% # filter for n == 1 and year 2018
  group_by(country) %>% 
  count()
```

Comment: also a better answer than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

text <-
  "userId,  login,      country
  132,     2017-01-01, A
  133,     2017-01-01, B
  133,     2018-01-01, B
  432,     2018-01-01, A"

df <- read.csv(text = text, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(yr = as.numeric(gsub("-.*", "", login)))

svnt_peeps <- df %>% filter(yr == 2017)

df %>%
  filter(yr == 2018) %>%
  anti_join(svnt_peeps, "userId") %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  count()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#> # Groups:   country [1]
#>   country     n
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 " A"        1
```

Comment: do you mean "B" has zero entries?

Comment: oh i like your answer more (the dplyr version)

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean B.